# Antd Datepicker date format

Tags: javascript, antd

I'm receiving data from API and passing it immediatly to `<Form>` `initialValue`. But `registerDate` is in string format like "01-01-2022" and when `<Form.Item>` is passing it into `<DatePicker>` i've got an error:

```
Error: t.clone is not a function [...]
```

How can I repair it? Can I format the date before passing it into `<Datepicker>` in `<Form.Item>`?

Code example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cxyphe

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the name in Form.Item is causing the problem. If you remove name from line 20 it should render the datePicker. [AntD](https://ant.design/components/form/) also some examples of using a date picker in a form.

Comment: yes, antd fills datepicker value depending on form.item name. But I need this name because I use it in on onFinish method.